# Django: correct order of these models

Tags: python, django, models

I have these models in my app models.py:

```
class A(models.Model):
    #some details
    pass


class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True)
    c = models.ForeignKey(C, null=True, blank=True)

class C(models.Model):
    pass

    def method(self):
        b_list = B.objects.filter(c=self)
        a_list = []
        for b in b_list:
            a_list.append(b.a)

        return a_list
```

this gives me an error when i launch the webserver because in B it declares that C is not defined.

then if i put these models in order A C B django tells me that B is not defined in C's method().

How can i resolve this "not defined" issue in this situation? it seems circular!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use a string in such cases:

```
class A(models.Model):
    #some details
    pass


class B(models.Model):
    a = models.ForeignKey("A", null=True, blank=True) # note the quotes
    c = models.ForeignKey("C", null=True, blank=True) # note the quotes

class C(models.Model):
    pass
```

If this was a more "extreme" case and you couldn't use this trick, declaring `C` first, then `A` and `B`, and after that `C.method` (`def C_method [...] C.method = C_method`) would have been the way to follow.